Why do blood vessels have M3 Receptors that can only be stimulated exogenously?
I'm going through pharmacology and this detail that our lecturer sort of brushed over sort of baffled me?
As far as I understand, endogenous means being stimulated by the body as part of a synapse, whereas exogenously means being stimulated by drugs being administered.
So, if M3 receptors are just lying there on the endothelium, with no synapses that link up to them, what context do they fire in "naturally"? Do they just not?

"endogenous means being stimulated by the body as part of a synapse" - endogenous just means that the signal is internally generated. It doesn't say a synapse is involved. Synapses are special structures involved in the nervous system. Signaling outside the nervous system is all non-synaptic (some signaling within the nervous system is also non-synaptic). I would question whether you understood what your instructor was actually saying; I doubt they referred to any receptor that can only be stimulated exogenously.
